# With a physical printer, the result of.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.PageMediaSizeName is always ISOA4

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, spooler, print-job-control

When I use the PrintServer class in c#, I get the print queues as well as the print jobs, but with an iR-ADVC3525 or with other physical printers, the result of `printJob.HostingPrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.PageMediaSizeName.ToString()` is always `ISOA4`. Even when I define the `ISOA3` or other format.

I tried to set my physical printer preferences to A3. So `printJob.HostingPrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.PageMediaSizeName.ToString()`  is `ISOA3`.

However, I want to retrieve information from the print spooler and not from the preferences

I've tried with `Microsoft Print to PDF` (virtual printer used to create PDF) and I get the ISOA3 format when I define it.

Here's my code that iterates over print jobs:

```cs
 public void CatchJobs()
 {
     PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();
     PrintQueueCollection printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues();
     foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in printQueues)
     {
         printQueue.Refresh();
         if (printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection() != null)
         {
             PrintJobInfoCollection printJobs = printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();

             foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo printJob in printJobs)
             {
                 Job job = new Job(printJob);
                 if (printJob.JobStatus.HasFlag(PrintJobStatus.Printed) && !Jobs.Contains(job))
                 {
                     lock (Jobs)
                     {
                         Jobs.Add(job);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Here's the constructor of my Job class:

```
 public Job(PrintSystemJobInfo printJob)
 {
     Name = printJob.Name;
     Status = printJob.JobStatus.ToString();
     Owner = Environment.UserName;
     Priority = printJob.Priority.ToString();
     TimeSubmitted = printJob.TimeJobSubmitted;
     Color = printJob.HostingPrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.OutputColor.Value.ToString();
     DriverName = printJob.HostingPrintQueue.FullName;
     JobId = printJob.JobIdentifier;
// Problem HERE
     string? paperSize = printJob.HostingPrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.PageMediaSizeName.ToString();
// End problem
 
     PaperSize = paperSize is null ? "format inconnu" : paperSize;
     double? paperLenght = printJob.HostingPrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Height;
     double? paperWidth = printJob.HostingPrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Width;
     PaperLength = paperLenght is null ? 0 : Math.Round((double)paperLenght * _pixelSize);
     PaperWidth = paperWidth is null ? 0 : Math.Round((double)paperWidth * _pixelSize);
     TotalPages = printJob.NumberOfPages;
 }
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solution will work with an `iR-ADVC3525` or other physical printer.

With a `Brother MFC-L8690CDW` series printer, using `managementObject` from `System.Management`.
I get the right information with this constructor:

```cs
        public Job(ManagementObject printJob)
        {
            Name = printJob["Name"].ToString();
            Status = printJob["Status"].ToString();
            Owner = printJob["Owner"].ToString();
            Priority = printJob["Priority"].ToString();
            TimeSubmitted = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(printJob["TimeSubmitted"].ToString());
            Color = printJob["Color"].ToString();
            DriverName = printJob["DriverName"].ToString();
            JobId = int.Parse(printJob["JobId"].ToString());
            PaperSize = printJob["PaperSize"].ToString();
            PaperLength = double.Parse(printJob["PaperLength"].ToString()) / 10;
            PaperWidth = double.Parse(printJob["PaperWidth"].ToString()) / 10;
            TotalPages = int.Parse(printJob["TotalPages"].ToString());
        }
```

to get the ManagementObject, i do this:

```cs
public void CatchJobs()
{
    string statusToCheck = "OK"; // Remplacez "Printed" par le statut recherché

    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob");
        ManagementObjectCollection printJobs = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject printJob in printJobs)
        {
            string status = printJob["Status"].ToString();
            if (status.Equals(statusToCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Job job = new Job(printJob);
                if (!Jobs.Contains(job))
                {
                    lock (Jobs)
                    {
                        Jobs.Add(job);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erreur : " + e.Message);
    }
}
```